# How to establish the connection between AWS database and Azure data Factory?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, azure

I am trying to establish the connection between MYSQL database which is in AWS and Azure Data Factory.I put the correct server name,database name,username,pw but everytime it was throwing time out error and  was unable to establish the connection between them.Can anyone help to resolve this issue?

Thank You,

Comment: Step 1. Move everything to Azure

Comment: It can be a firewall issue?